# Reduce amount of trucks in a multi-product transportation problem

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, operations-research

Imagine this situation:

```
In a certain city are a number of suppliers and a number of customers. Each 
customer demands a certain amount of several different products. Each 
supplier has a certain amount of each of these products in stock. Trucks 
with unlimited capacity transport multiple (different) products from only 
one supplier to only one customer, but each trip costs the same lot of 
money.
```

Now the question is:

```
How can the cheapest way be found to deliver all demanded products to the 
customers?
```

I think that there should be some algorithm around solving this problem as it is a quiet standard one. But I have done some research and I am not able to find it. 
I think it is not a standard Transportation Problem, because more products are involved and costs are not defined per transferred product.

Any ideas or links will be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understand the question correctly (the wording is a bit vague in places), it can be modeled as an integer linear program. As far as "standard" problem types that might apply, I think you can formulate it as a [one-dimensional cutting stock problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutting_stock_problem). What would be a piece of "stock material" now becomes a truck from a specific supplier to a specific customer. A "pattern" is now a possible load for a given truck (so much of this product, so much of that product, ...). Since the trucks have unlimited capacity, the limitation on what goes in a pattern is the lesser of how much of each product the supplier has and how much the customer wants. The "waste" for a pattern translates to the cost of dispatching the truck.

While it can be formulated that way, I would not recommend doing so.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. An integer linear programming model seems to be applicable indeed. I expected it to be a special form of the transportation problem, but it seems that that isn't true. 
The one dimensional cutting stock problem cannot be used, as far as I do understand it, as it does not adress the total problem but only the individual truck load.

Comment: I do think the 1D cutting stock approach would work. As I said, each truck represents a piece of "stock", which can be "cut" (loaded) with different patterns. The cutting stock problem selects which stock (trucks) to use with which patterns (loads) to meet demand.

Comment: I like the way you think, but I think the cutting stock problem does not chose which trucks to load. It chooses how many trucks to load. And adding trucks with unlimited capacity will definitely result in chosing only one truck. I don't see how other limitations could be implemented when the 'raw material' has an unlimited size.

Comment: In hindsight, I don't think the cutting stock approach works due to the limited supplies at suppliers. I think I can recast it as a variant of a cutting stock problem with a nonstandard cost function (the cost would involve interactions between the patterns used), and I suspect the usual column generation heuristic could be made to worth, but I very much doubt it's worth screwing with.